# MySQL WHERE statement for finding expiry date within 2 days

Tags: mysql, date, where-clause

I have a column named expiry which holds the expiry date of the item in timestamp format.

How would I execute a MySQL query to only select items with an expiry date within 2 days?

Thanks!!

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE expiry BETWEEN(TODAY(), TODAY() + 2)
```

Comment: I tried all the methods here but they didn't work. I figured since the actual column is an integer, but my script is saving a timestamp in that location. The following worked:

expire - ".mktime()." < 172800

Comment: some table structure and data would help us pretty much

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from mytable
where expiry between now() and adddate(now(), INTERVAL 2 DAY);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE DATEDIFF(expire, NOW()) <= 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ...
WHERE expiry <= NOW()+"2 days";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE dateCol <= date_sub(now(), interval 2 day);
```